# Sanic (asyncio + uvloop webserver) - Return a custom response

Tags: python, python-3.5, python-asyncio, sanic

I'm starting with [Sanic](https://github.com/channelcat/sanic)...

> Sanic is a Flask-like Python 3.5+ web server that's written to go
>   fast. (...)
>   On top of being Flask-like, Sanic supports async request handlers.
>   This means you can use the new shiny async/await syntax from Python
>   3.5, making your code non-blocking and speedy.

... and until this point, there are very few examples on how to use him and the docs are not so good.

Following the docs basic example, we have

```
from sanic import Sanic
from sanic.response import json

app = Sanic()

@app.route("/")
async def test(request):
    return json({"test": True})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

How can I return a custom response with a custom status code, for example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In [Sanic](https://github.com/channelcat/sanic) the HTTP responses are instances of [HTTPResponse](https://github.com/channelcat/sanic/blob/master/sanic/response.py), as you can see in its below code implementation, and the functions `json`, `text` and `html` just encapsulated the object creation, following the [factory pattern](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Factory.html)

> ```
> from ujson import dumps as json_dumps
>  ...    
>
> def json(body, status=200, headers=None):
>     return HTTPResponse(json_dumps(body), headers=headers, status=status,
>     content_type="application/json")
>
>
>
> def text(body, status=200, headers=None):
>     return HTTPResponse(body, status=status, headers=headers,
>                         content_type="text/plain; charset=utf-8")
>
>
> def html(body, status=200, headers=None):
>     return HTTPResponse(body, status=status, headers=headers,
>                         content_type="text/html; charset=utf-8")
> ```

The function `json({"test": True})` just dumps a `dict` object as a JSON string using the ultra fast [ujson](https://github.com/esnme/ultrajson) and set the `content_type` param.

So you can return a custom status code returning `json({"message": "bla"}, status=201)` or creating a `HTTPResponse` as the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Example from [documentation](https://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sanic/response.html#modify-headers-or-status)

```
from sanic import response

@app.route('/json')
def handle_request(request):
    return response.json(
        {'message': 'Hello world!'},
        headers={'X-Served-By': 'sanic'},
        status=200
    )
```